# C++ concurrency library

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

I started a C++11 library of concurrency primitives in order to

1. study and compare their performance;
2. provide high-quality implementation of those to use in my projects.

Its main target platform is Linux x86-64. It relies upon the `futex()` system call for some of its functionality. Other parts of the library are platform-independent though.

The full source code of the library could be found [here](https://github.com/ademakov/Evenk).

First, there are 3 families of synchronisation objects: wrappers for standard C++ library mutex and condition variables, then similar pthread-based objects, and finally futex-based objects. They share a common set of methods and thus are interchangeable as template parameters.

```
#ifndef EVENK_SYNCH_H_
#define EVENK_SYNCH_H_

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <system_error>

#include <pthread.h>

#include "evenk/backoff.h"
#include "evenk/futex.h"

namespace ev {
namespace concurrency {

//
// Mutexes
//

class StdMutex : public std::mutex {
 public:
  void Lock() { lock(); }
  void Unlock() { unlock(); }
};

class PosixMutex {
 public:
  PosixMutex() noexcept : mutex_(PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER) {}

  PosixMutex(const PosixMutex&) = delete;
  PosixMutex& operator=(const PosixMutex&) = delete;

  ~PosixMutex() noexcept { pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_); }

  void Lock() {
    int ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    if (ret)
      throw std::system_error(ret, std::system_category(),
                              "pthread_mutex_lock()");
  }

  void Unlock() {
    int ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
    if (ret)
      throw std::system_error(ret, std::system_category(),
                              "pthread_mutex_unlock()");
  }

 private:
  friend class PosixCondVar;

  pthread_mutex_t mutex_;
};

class FutexLock {
 public:
  FutexLock() noexcept : futex_(0) {}

  FutexLock(const FutexLock&) = delete;
  FutexLock& operator=(const FutexLock&) = delete;

  void Lock() { Lock(NoBackoff{}); }

  template <typename Backoff>
  void Lock(Backoff backoff) {
    for (std::uint32_t value = 0; !futex_.compare_exchange_strong(
             value, 1, std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_relaxed);
         value = 0) {
      if (backoff()) {
        if (value == 2 || futex_.exchange(2, std::memory_order_acquire)) {
          do
            futex_wait(futex_, 2);
          while (futex_.exchange(2, std::memory_order_acquire));
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  void Unlock() {
    if (futex_.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) != 1) {
      futex_.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
      ev::futex_wake(futex_, 1);
    }
  }

 private:
  friend class FutexCondVar;

  std::atomic<std::uint32_t> futex_;
};

//
// Lock Guard
//

template <typename LockType>
class LockGuard {
 public:
  LockGuard(LockType& lock) : lock_ptr_(&lock), owns_lock_(false) { Lock(); }

  template <typename Backoff>
  LockGuard(LockType& lock, Backoff backoff)
      : lock_ptr_(&lock), owns_lock_(false) {
    Lock(backoff);
  }

  LockGuard(LockType& lock, std::adopt_lock_t) noexcept : lock_ptr_(&lock),
                                                          owns_lock_(true) {}

  LockGuard(LockType& lock, std::defer_lock_t) noexcept : lock_ptr_(&lock),
                                                          owns_lock_(false) {}

  LockGuard(const LockGuard&) = delete;
  LockGuard& operator=(const LockGuard&) = delete;

  ~LockGuard() {
    if (owns_lock_) lock_ptr_->Unlock();
  }

  void Lock() {
    lock_ptr_->Lock();
    owns_lock_ = true;
  }

  template <typename Backoff>
  void Lock(Backoff backoff) {
    lock_ptr_->Lock(backoff);
    owns_lock_ = true;
  }

  void Unlock() {
    lock_ptr_->Unlock();
    owns_lock_ = false;
  }

  LockType* GetLockPtr() { return lock_ptr_; }

  bool OwnsLock() { return owns_lock_; }

 private:
  LockType* lock_ptr_;
  bool owns_lock_;
};

//
// Condition Variables
//

class StdCondVar : public std::condition_variable {
 public:
  void Wait(LockGuard<StdMutex>& guard) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*guard.GetLockPtr(), std::adopt_lock);
    wait(lock);
    lock.release();
  }

  void NotifyOne() { notify_one(); }
  void NotifyAll() { notify_all(); }
};

class PosixCondVar {
 public:
  PosixCondVar() noexcept : condition_(PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER) {}

  PosixCondVar(const PosixCondVar&) = delete;
  PosixCondVar& operator=(const PosixCondVar&) = delete;

  ~PosixCondVar() noexcept { pthread_cond_destroy(&condition_); }

  void Wait(LockGuard<PosixMutex>& guard) {
    int ret = pthread_cond_wait(&condition_, &guard.GetLockPtr()->mutex_);
    if (ret)
      throw std::system_error(ret, std::system_category(),
                              "pthread_cond_wait()");
  }

  void NotifyOne() {
    int ret = pthread_cond_signal(&condition_);
    if (ret)
      throw std::system_error(ret, std::system_category(),
                              "pthread_cond_signal()");
  }

  void NotifyAll() {
    int ret = pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition_);
    if (ret)
      throw std::system_error(ret, std::system_category(),
                              "pthread_cond_broadcast()");
  }

 private:
  pthread_cond_t condition_;
};

class FutexCondVar {
 public:
  FutexCondVar() noexcept : futex_(0), count_(0), owner_(nullptr) {}

  FutexCondVar(const FutexCondVar&) = delete;
  FutexCondVar& operator=(const FutexCondVar&) = delete;

  void Wait(LockGuard<FutexLock>& guard) {
    FutexLock* owner = guard.GetLockPtr();
    if (owner_ != nullptr && owner_ != owner)
      throw std::invalid_argument(
          "different locks used for the same condition variable.");
    owner_.store(owner, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    count_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel);
    std::uint32_t value = futex_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

    owner->Unlock();

    ev::futex_wait(futex_, value);

    count_.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (owner->futex_.exchange(2, std::memory_order_acquire))
      futex_wait(owner->futex_, 2);
  }

  void NotifyOne() {
    futex_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (count_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) ev::futex_wake(futex_, 1);
  }

  void NotifyAll() {
    futex_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (count_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
      FutexLock* owner = owner_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
      if (owner) ev::futex_requeue(futex_, 1, INT_MAX, owner->futex_);
    }
  }

 private:
  std::atomic<std::uint32_t> futex_;
  std::atomic<std::uint32_t> count_;
  std::atomic<FutexLock*> owner_;
};

//
// Synchronization Traits
//

class StdSynch {
 public:
  using LockType = StdMutex;
  using CondVarType = StdCondVar;
};

class PosixSynch {
 public:
  using LockType = PosixMutex;
  using CondVarType = PosixCondVar;
};

class FutexSynch {
 public:
  using LockType = FutexLock;
  using CondVarType = FutexCondVar;
};

#if __linux__
using DefaultSynch = FutexSynch;
#else
using DefaultSynch = StdSynch;
#endif

}  // namespace concurrency
}  // namespace ev

#endif  // !EVENK_SYNCH_H_
```

A simple concurrent queue on top of the standard deque and above synchronisation primitives is defined as follows:

```
#ifndef EVENK_QUEUE_H_
#define EVENK_QUEUE_H_

#include <deque>

#include "evenk/synch.h"

namespace ev {
namespace concurrency {

template <typename ValueType, typename SynchPolicy = DefaultSynch,
          typename Sequence = std::deque<ValueType>>
class Queue {
 public:
  Queue() noexcept : finish_(false) {}

  Queue(Queue&& other) noexcept : finish_(other.finish_) {
    std::swap(queue_, other.queue_);
  }

  bool Empty() const {
    LockGuard<LockType> guard(lock_);
    return queue_.empty();
  }

  bool Finished() const { return finish_; }

  void Finish() {
    LockGuard<LockType> guard(lock_);
    finish_ = true;
    cond_.NotifyAll();
  }

  template <typename... Backoff>
  void Enqueue(ValueType&& data, Backoff... backoff) {
    LockGuard<LockType> guard(lock_, std::forward<Backoff>(backoff)...);
    queue_.push_back(std::move(data));
    cond_.NotifyOne();
  }

  template <typename... Backoff>
  void Enqueue(const ValueType& data, Backoff... backoff) {
    LockGuard<LockType> guard(lock_, std::forward<Backoff>(backoff)...);
    queue_.push_back(data);
    cond_.NotifyOne();
  }

  template <typename... Backoff>
  bool Dequeue(ValueType& data, Backoff... backoff) {
    LockGuard<LockType> guard(lock_, std::forward<Backoff>(backoff)...);
    while (queue_.empty()) {
      if (Finished()) return false;
      cond_.Wait(guard);
    }
    data = std::move(queue_.front());
    queue_.pop_front();
    return true;
  }

 private:
  using LockType = typename SynchPolicy::LockType;
  using CondVarType = typename SynchPolicy::CondVarType;

  bool finish_;
  LockType lock_;
  CondVarType cond_;
  Sequence queue_;
};

}  // namespace concurrency
}  // namespace ev

#endif  // !EVENK_QUEUE_H_
```

Also there is a bounded queue that is normally faster than the standard queue. The bounded queue has a number of separate slots. For each enqueue or dequeue operation a slot is assigned using atomic tail and head counters. There are several methods to synchronise access to slots. One is based on busy waiting, another on mutexes and condition variables, and another on direct use of futexes.

```
#ifndef EVENK_BOUNDED_QUEUE_H_
#define EVENK_BOUNDED_QUEUE_H_

#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>

#include "evenk/backoff.h"
#include "evenk/basic.h"
#include "evenk/futex.h"
#include "evenk/synch.h"

namespace ev {
namespace concurrency {

struct BoundedQueueSlotBase {
 public:
  void Initialize(std::uint32_t value) {
    ticket_.store(value, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  }

  std::uint32_t Load() const { return ticket_.load(std::memory_order_acquire); }

  void Store(std::uint32_t value) {
    ticket_.store(value, std::memory_order_release);
  }

 protected:
  std::atomic<std::uint32_t> ticket_;
};

class BoundedQueueNoWait : public BoundedQueueSlotBase {
 public:
  std::uint32_t WaitAndLoad(std::uint32_t) { return Load(); }

  void StoreAndWake(std::uint32_t value) { Store(value); }

  void Wake() {}
};

class BoundedQueueYieldWait : public BoundedQueueSlotBase {
 public:
  std::uint32_t WaitAndLoad(std::uint32_t) {
    std::this_thread::yield();
    return Load();
  }

  void StoreAndWake(std::uint32_t value) { Store(value); }

  void Wake() {}
};

class BoundedQueueFutexWait : public BoundedQueueSlotBase {
 public:
  std::uint32_t WaitAndLoad(std::uint32_t value) {
    wait_count_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    ev::futex_wait(ticket_, value);  // Presuming this is a full memory fence.
    wait_count_.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    return Load();
  }

  void StoreAndWake(std::uint32_t value) {
    Store(value);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    if (wait_count_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) Wake();
  }

  void Wake() { futex_wake(ticket_, INT32_MAX); }

 private:
  std::atomic<std::uint32_t> wait_count_ = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);
};

template <typename Synch = DefaultSynch>
class BoundedQueueSynchWait : public BoundedQueueSlotBase {
 public:
  std::uint32_t WaitAndLoad(std::uint32_t value) {
    LockGuard<LockType> guard(lock_);
    std::uint32_t current_value = ticket_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (current_value == value) {
      cond_.Wait(guard);
      current_value = ticket_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    return current_value;
  }

  void StoreAndWake(std::uint32_t value) {
    LockGuard<LockType> guard(lock_);
    ticket_.store(value, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    cond_.NotifyAll();
  }

  void Wake() {
    LockGuard<LockType> guard(lock_);
    cond_.NotifyAll();
  }

 private:
  using LockType = typename Synch::LockType;
  using CondVarType = typename Synch::CondVarType;

  LockType lock_;
  CondVarType cond_;
};

template <typename ValueType, typename WaitType = BoundedQueueNoWait>
class BoundedQueue {
 public:
  BoundedQueue(std::uint32_t size)
      : ring_{nullptr}, mask_{size - 1}, finish_{false}, head_{0}, tail_{0} {
    if (size == 0 || (size & mask_) != 0)
      throw std::invalid_argument("BoundedQueue size must be a power of two");

    void* ring;
    if (::posix_memalign(&ring, ev::kCacheLineSize, size * sizeof(Slot)))
      throw std::bad_alloc();

    ring_ = new (ring) Slot[size];
    for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++) ring_[i].Initialize(i);
  }

  BoundedQueue(BoundedQueue&& other) noexcept : ring_{other.ring_},
                                                mask_{other.mask_},
                                                finish_{false},
                                                head_{0},
                                                tail_{0} {
    other.ring_ = nullptr;
  }

  BoundedQueue(BoundedQueue const&) = delete;
  BoundedQueue& operator=(BoundedQueue const&) = delete;

  ~BoundedQueue() { Destroy(); }

  bool Empty() const {
    int64_t head = head_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    int64_t tail = tail_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    return (tail <= head);
  }

  bool Finished() const { return finish_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); }

  void Finish() {
    finish_.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i < mask_ + 1; i++) ring_[i].Wake();
  }

  template <typename... Backoff>
  void Enqueue(ValueType&& value, Backoff... backoff) {
    const std::uint64_t tail = tail_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    Slot& slot = ring_[tail & mask_];
    WaitTail(slot, tail, std::forward<Backoff>(backoff)...);
    slot.value = std::move(value);
    WakeHead(slot, tail + 1);
  }

  template <typename... Backoff>
  void Enqueue(const ValueType& value, Backoff... backoff) {
    const std::uint64_t tail = tail_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    Slot& slot = ring_[tail & mask_];
    WaitTail(slot, tail, std::forward<Backoff>(backoff)...);
    slot.value = value;
    WakeHead(slot, tail + 1);
  }

  template <typename... Backoff>
  bool Dequeue(ValueType& value, Backoff... backoff) {
    const std::uint64_t head = head_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    Slot& slot = ring_[head & mask_];
    if (!WaitHead(slot, head + 1, std::forward<Backoff>(backoff)...))
      return false;
    value = std::move(slot.value);
    WakeTail(slot, head + mask_ + 1);
    return true;
  }

 private:
  struct alignas(ev::kCacheLineSize) Slot : public WaitType {
    ValueType value;
  };

  void Destroy() {
    if (ring_ != nullptr) {
      std::uint32_t size = mask_ + 1;
      for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++) ring_[i].~Slot();
      std::free(ring_);
    }
  }

  void WaitTail(Slot& slot, std::uint64_t required_ticket) {
    std::uint32_t current_ticket = slot.Load();
    while (current_ticket != std::uint32_t(required_ticket)) {
      current_ticket = slot.WaitAndLoad(current_ticket);
    }
  }

  template <typename Backoff>
  void WaitTail(Slot& slot, std::uint64_t required_ticket, Backoff backoff) {
    bool waiting = false;
    std::uint32_t current_ticket = slot.Load();
    while (current_ticket != std::uint32_t(required_ticket)) {
      if (waiting) {
        current_ticket = slot.WaitAndLoad(current_ticket);
      } else {
        waiting = backoff();
        current_ticket = slot.Load();
      }
    }
  }

  bool WaitHead(Slot& slot, std::uint64_t required_ticket) {
    std::uint32_t current_ticket = slot.Load();
    while (current_ticket != std::uint32_t(required_ticket)) {
      if (Finished()) {
        std::uint64_t tail = tail_.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
        if (required_ticket >= tail) return false;
      }
      current_ticket = slot.WaitAndLoad(current_ticket);
    }
    return true;
  }

  template <typename Backoff>
  bool WaitHead(Slot& slot, std::uint64_t required_ticket, Backoff backoff) {
    bool waiting = false;
    std::uint32_t current_ticket = slot.Load();
    while (current_ticket != std::uint32_t(required_ticket)) {
      if (Finished()) {
        std::uint64_t tail = tail_.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
        if (required_ticket >= tail) return false;
      }
      if (waiting) {
        current_ticket = slot.WaitAndLoad(current_ticket);
      } else {
        waiting = backoff();
        current_ticket = slot.Load();
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  void WakeHead(Slot& slot, std::uint32_t new_ticket) {
    slot.StoreAndWake(new_ticket);
  }

  void WakeTail(Slot& slot, std::uint32_t new_ticket) {
    slot.StoreAndWake(new_ticket);
  }

  Slot* ring_;
  const std::uint32_t mask_;

  std::atomic<bool> finish_;

  alignas(ev::kCacheLineSize) std::atomic<std::uint64_t> head_;
  alignas(ev::kCacheLineSize) std::atomic<std::uint64_t> tail_;
};

template <typename ValueType>
using DefaultBoundedQueue = BoundedQueue<ValueType, BoundedQueueNoWait>;

}  // namespace concurrency
}  // namespace ev

#endif  // !EVENK_BOUNDED_QUEUE_H_
```

A benchmark for different variants of queues is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ademakov/Evenk/blob/master/tests/concurrency-queue-bench.cc).

Comment: Why would you not just use the version that is provided by the compiler. You would expect the implementation to use the most efficient technique (and if it does not then it will eventually and your code gets upgraded for free with a re-compile).

Comment: I implemented synchronisation mechanisms in a very flexible way to experiment with them and find the best choice for particular usage scenario. The solution provided by the compiler does not have to be and cannot be the best in every possible case. It just has to be good enough for average use. If you run the provided benchmark you could see that mechanisms based on busy-waiting and futexes significantly outperform std::mutex and std::condition_variable in certain cases. So if you have an application that suffers from poor multi-threading performance then using my library might be an answer.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::future` and `std::promise`.

Comment: `std::future` and `std::promise` use hidden behind the scenes atomic operations and memory allocation. This could affect performance of very high-load applications. I will probably provide in the future a convenient higher-level interface that would use these objects. So a user will have a choice between familiar high-level interface and extremely efficient low-level interface.

Comment: @AlekseyDemakov I may be wong but I think that libstdc++ uses futexes to implement the concurrency features of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reinventing the wheel

When C++11 introducing support for threading, it introduced two concepts: a lockable object, and a lock. A lockable object meets, at the very least:

[image]

and has several examples in the standard library (`std::mutex`, `std::timed_mutex`, `std::recursive_mutex`, `std::recursive_timed_mutex`, `std::shared_mutex`, and `std::shared_timed_mutex`).

A lock is something which, for lack of a better description, locks a lockable object. The simplest lock in the standard library is `std::lock_guard`, which is just an RAII scoped lock templated on a `BasicLockable` and can be implemented via:

```
template <class BasicLockable>
class lock_guard {
public:
    lock_guard(BasicLockable& mtx)
    : mtx(mtx) 
    {
        mtx.lock(); 
    }

    ~lock_guard()
    {
        mtx.unlock();
    }

    lock_guard(const lock_guard&) = delete;
    lock_guard& operator=(const lock_guard&) = delete;
private:
    BasicLockable& mtx;
};
```

#### C++11 Concepts

The C++11 concept for BasicLockable is `lock()` and `unlock()`, not `Lock()` and `Unlock()`. If you simply follow the concept, you could directly replace `StdMutex`, `LockGuard<T>` and `StdCondVar` with `std::mutex`, `std::unique_lock<T>` and `std::condition_variable`. By choosing to invent your own convention, you gave yourself more work!

It's not just an extra work issue either. What you ended up with is strictly worse than what the standard provides, for several reasons.

1. `LockGuard<T>` is more expensive than `std::lock_guard<T>` in those cases where you really just need a scoped lock (e.g. in `Empty()`).
2. Where you do need the functionality provided by `unique_lock<T>`, you don't have the complete functionality of it. You are missing:
   a. `try_lock()`, `try_lock_for()`, `try_lock_until()`. Those functions may not be supported by all lockable objects (they require a stronger concept than simply `BasicLockable`), but if your lockable supports it, your lock should do.
   b. Construction with `std::try_to_lock_t`. Technically, it is constructible with this type, but it will fail to compile when you try to pass that into `Lock()`.
   c. `std::unique_lock<T>` is and move-constructible, yours is not.
3. `std::condition_variable` has some handy member functions that are missing here as well: `wait_for()` and `wait_until()`.

None of these is difficult to add - but there's no reason to do it in the first place, unless as an exercise.

#### Naming Conventions

`UpperCamelCase` is a common naming convention for types - but definitely not for member functions. It reads incredibly awkwardly. The fact that the Google Style guide suggests this is a huge knock against that style guide - *especially* since they differentiate the naming between different kinds of functions! Encapsulation is still a thing.

#### Back-off

The back-off algorithm should not be part of the `lock()`, it's external to that. Otherwise, you're breaking the Single Responsibility Principle. Your lock should lock - your algorithm should backoff.

Your use of `forward` is unnecessary as there are no references here - everything is a value, so it's equivalent to `move()`. None of your backoffs have allocated state, so simply passing them by value would've been also equivalent and less typing. But since logically there can only be one (or zero) backoff(s), prefer to make that much clearer from the interface by providing a default argument of your `NoBackoff`. Lastly, regarding previous comments about concepts and naming conventions, prefer push and pop:

```
template <class Backoff=NoBackoff>
void push(ValueType const& data, Backoff backoff = NoBackoff{})
{
    backoff();
    std::lock_guard<Mutex> guard(lock_);
    queue_.emplace_back(data);
    cond_.notify_one();
}
```

Comment: In computer science the lock and the mutex are the same thing. Hence I don't confuse anything, I just use proper naming. I find the usage of the word "lock" by the c++ standard library quite arbitrary and confusing. The StdMutex and PosixMutex are named after their underlying counterparts, conceptually they are just locks (in the real CS sense, not in the pervert c++ library sense). The classes and methods again are capitalised as per different naming conventions. You can't replace FutexSyncVar with std::condition_variable. This is where the real stuff is. The Std and Posix things are trivial.

Comment: @AlekseyDemakov When your poor choice of naming leads you to have to write extra classes for no reason, that's not trivia. Also, I don't know what you fail to understand about the difference between a mutex (that which can be locked) and a lock (that which does the locking). The fact that the theory abstracts away the difference doesn't mean there isn't one or that it's "perverted".

Comment: @AlekseyDemakov Also that style guide should be avoided.

Comment: My library source code available on github includes such things as `SpinLock` and `TicketLock`. These are well-known names that predate the C++ standard naming choice by decades. Calling them `SpinMutex` and `TicketMutex` would be confusing. Everybody with a background in concurrency immediately recognises what is `SpinLock` but would be lost with `SpinMutex`. Using the correct term for them but leaving the usage of "lock" in the C++ standard sense would be confusing as well.  The thing is the C++ standards committee irreparably corrupted their concurrency naming space. I just fixed this.

Comment: Your comments about backoff are incorrect. Backoff algorithm is used as a parameter for spin locks and futex-based locks. Backoff algorithm cannot be separated from them. Conversely, for PosixLock and StdLock the backoff does not apply at all, hence using `NoBackoff` as a default will not work for them

Comment: The inefficiency of my lock guard is doubtful. In simple cases any decent compiler after inlining would see that the if condition is always true and will optimise it away. So the binary code will be as efficient as if using a simple scoped lock. In more complicated cases, when the compiler is unable to optimise the check, the cost of the check would be likely negligible compared to the sync overhead. And most of the time the CPU branch predictor should be able to make it virtually zero. I don't need pointless bloat in my library. A single guard class is good enough for any real-life use.